# Stop animation immediately jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an animation every one second and I have a button Stop, when I click to the button the animation is stopped but it continues after. There is not another way to remove the animation ?
This is my  [code](http://jsfiddle.net/Mils/UxTdU/10/).

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#myImg").animate({top: '50%',left: '50%',width: '174px',height: '174px',padding: '10px'}, 500);
         $("#myImg").animate({ marginTop: '0',marginLeft: '0',top: '0',left: '0',width: '70px',height: '70px',padding: '5px'}, 600); 
   },1000);    
});


$("#stop").click(function(){
$("#myImg").stop();
});
```

​
Thank you

Comment: you have 500 + 600 in an interval of 1000, couldnt be that?

Comment: yes, but this is not the problem : http://jsfiddle.net/Mils/UxTdU/11/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UxTdU/15/)*

1. -You don't need setInterval, you can use the `.animate()` callback to loop your `anim` function.
2. -Nest your animate functions
3. -Use the `.stop()` method on your first `.animate()` iteration just to prevent animation buildups and clear some animation memory ;)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    
   function anim(){
       $("#myImg").stop().animate({top: '50%',left: '50%',width: '174px',height: '174px',padding: '10px'}, 500, function(){
            $(this).animate({ marginTop: '0',marginLeft: '0',top: '0',left: '0',width: '70px',height: '70px',padding: '5px'}, 600, anim); // <-- the 'anim' callback
       });    // SCROLL THERE --> TO FIND THE CALLBACK :D --> 
    }
    anim(); // run!!



    $("#stop").click(function(){
        $("#myImg").stop();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `setInterval()` call is **continuously** adding in new calls to `.animate()` to your elements. That means that you succeed in stopping the animation, then the `setInterval()` calls it *again*, making the animation run again.

Why do you have this on `setInterval()`?

In any case, you'll have to cancel the schedule as well. You can do that by doing something similar to the following:

```
var schedule = setInterval(fn, 1000);
clearInterval(schedule);
```